# Sum convergence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I would expect the following sum to converge:

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n=0
$$

Indeed I get:

```
Sum[n,{n,-10^7,10^7}]
(*0*)
```

But running `Sum[n, {n, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` I get a warning that it does not converge. Thus my questions are:

- Mathematically speaking, is MMA correct? Am I mistaken to expect convergence. Clearly this is a delicate sum as breaking it into two sums for positive an negative values of `n` would indeed make a difference.
- Asumming that I'm correct to expect convergence, can I make MMA comply?

Edit:

Following the debate in comments, I asked the question also on Math S.E. to answer the mathematical point of my question. See link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501429/question-about-convergence-of-series/2501444?noredirect=1#comment5166662_2501444).

Perhaps rephrasing my question the correct question to ask here would be:

Can I force MMA to calculate convergence in the Cauchy P.V. sense for discrete sums similar to the option in `Integrate`?

Comment: After adding an extra `x^k` factor, you can split: `Sum[k x^k, {k, -∞, -1}] + Sum[k x^k, {k, 0, ∞}]` or unsymmetrize: `Sum[k x^k + (-k x^-k), {k, 0, ∞}]`.

Comment: But shouldn't the sum converge the way I entered it?

Comment: That's a math question, not a *Mathematica* question. It's akin to the question of what $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,\mathrm dx$ is, where you can interpret it in the Cauchy principal-value sense to get a finite result.

Comment: It is a MMA question, as according to the Cauchy P.V. which you mentioned this improper integral vanishes, as MMA itself finds by asking it to compute `Integrate[x, {x, -∞, ∞}, PrincipalValue -> True]`. For some reason though it is unable to do the same with the discrete summation version.

Comment: Consider the following grouping of the summands: $$0 + 1 + 2 + (3 - 2 - 1) + 4 + 5 + 6 + (7 - 3 - 4) +8+9+10+(11-5-6)+\cdots$$

Comment: I fail to see your point. However, trivially this sum should on mathematical grounds may be showed to converge by taking the limit $N\to\infty$ and summing from $-N$ to $N$. This works also in MMA as putting `Sum[n, {n, -N0, N0}]` yields the result of zero which identiaclly, and therefore `Limit[Sum[n, {n, -N0, N0}], N0 -> \[Infinity]]` is evaluated to 0 correctly.

Comment: For such sequences that are (clearly) not absolutely convergent the "value" of the series  depends on ordering. E.g. you can get every arbitrary value when reordering the alternating harmonic sequence.

Comment: I see a mathematics question (or ambiguity) re: whether that notation denotes `lim n->Inf, Sum[..{-n,n}]` or should we expect convergence as the limits are approached independently.

Comment: This can be done with Ramanujan summation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_⋯ which is very seldom used.

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion You cannot "group" like this, because it is not even a grouping, this is a rearrangment. Even worse if both positive and negative terms are divergent Riemann series theorem may apply: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4356473/756502 It does not converge, it is not even bounded (on both sides??). But even then, if we select 0 as a limit, does it really goes close or equel to 0 infinite ammount of times? No, it does not if we sum from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Because what you are really asking is

```
 Limit[Sum[n, {n, -mm, mm}], mm -> Infinity]
 (* 0 *)
```

That is probably how you should code it in your work. Even something like

```
 Limit[Sum[n, {n, -mm, mm+1}], mm -> Infinity]
 (* ∞ *)
```

Has an upper and lower bound for the summation limits of infinity, but now (properly) gives you a result of Infinity.

Comment: I wonder however if this could generalized in a robust manner to a more general case with a note complex expression within the sum. Will the runtime be reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

One cannot, in general add $-\infty$ (the left-half of the sum) and $+\infty$ (the right-half of the sum) and expect a unique answer because $-\infty+\infty=$ *indeterminate*. The problem as stated is a variant of a [conditionally convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence) sum.  That is, the sum is indeterminate depending on how the addition is performed; in what order the terms are summed. **Edit:** In general, if $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ converges but  $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty |x_n|$ is divergent, then convergence is conditional and not absolute. Although this is most often applied to alternating sign series, the order of signs is either irrelevant or the series is conditionally convergent. As such, there is no unique answer, see [Mathworld commentary](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConditionalConvergence.html).

Comment: For the last sentence, if $x_n=1/n^2$, you're saying $\sum 1/n^2$ does not converge absolutely?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Right, will change.